# Rtools 4.0 (Rstudio falsely claims it was deleted)

Tags: r, rstudio, rtools

I installed Rtools following the [official guide](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) (installing as well as adding the .Renviron file with the PATH).

Rstudio, however, doesn't recognise the installation:

```
> devtools::find_rtools()
```

`WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but the version of Rtools previously installed in C:/rtools40 has been deleted.`

Rtools is installed and seems to work:

[image: Screenshot, showing that Rtools has not been uninstalled]

Set-up: Windows 10, RStudio 1.2.5042, R 4.0.0, RTools 4.0

Comment: Isn't this a question for RStudio support (or the maintainer of `devtools`)?

Comment: Did you use writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con =
             "~/.Renviron") instead of writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron") ?

Comment: Do other indicators from within R show Rtools working? For example, do you get the expected output from `Sys.which("make")`? Are you able to install a package from source, e.g. `install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")`? (These are examples given on that installation guide you link).