# Rtools 4.0 not found during package installation

Tags: r, failed-installation, rstan, rtools

For many R packages I try to install (on my Windows 10 machine), I get a warning:

```
> install.packages('rstan')
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

I thought this was just an erroneous error message since the installation seemed to proceed anyway, but recently I tried to install a package (rstan) and found it completely nonfunctional. My hunch is that since rstan relies *completely* on compiling code with rcpp, maybe I only got away with the previous packages because I wasn't using the functions in them that relied on Rtools.

I reinstalled Rtools 4.0, and `devtools::find_rtools()` returns `TRUE`. But when I run `Sys.getenv()['PATH']` there is no Rtools on the path. There isn't a place in the installation process to tell it I want Rtools on the path either, so [these instructions](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/installing-rtools-for-compiled-code-via-rcpp/) don't help - the menus they refer to don't exist for me. So I thought this might be an issue where the new Rtools 4.0 doesn't put itself on the system path. But the problem persisted even after I directly edited the Windows path environment variables (both system and user versions) to include the path given to me by `pkgbuild::rtools_path()` (`C:\rtools40\usr\bin`, a path which both exists and appears to be correct).

This doesn't seem to be the same problem as [Rtools 4.0 (Rstudio falsely claims it was deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695991/rtools-4-0-rstudio-falsely-claims-it-was-deleted), since there are no claims Rtools was deleted. It's also not the same as [Rtools not being detected by R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r) as far as I can tell: I'm not leaving any features out of my Rtools installation - I'm not even getting the option to in my install wizard.

Would appreciate any advice or recommendations.

Comment: Have you read the instructions about putting RTools to your PATH [from here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)? Update the PATH variable in your `~/.Renviron` file to include the bin directory of the RTools directory. Also, make sure to install the RTools version matching your R version.

Comment: @Abdou this solved my problem! I overlooked the new instruction in the rtools40 installation process. If you submit this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rtools40` requires that you add its bin directory to your `PATH` variable. The full instructions are [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

You can update your `~/.Renviron` file with any of the following methods:

You can do that manually by opening `~/.Renviron` and putting the following in it:

```
PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"
```

You can also use R (Gui or RStudio or Shell) with the following:

```
writeLines(
    'PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"',
    con = file("~/.Renviron", open = "a")
)
```

Both of these methods require a restart of R.

Comment: I've installed RTools40 on my local d drive and I'm running this code but still cant load it into R, could you clarify if there is a step im missing, what is the 'PATH' variable

Comment: @BenjYoung https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them