# Error attaching rstan package: Entry Point Not Found

Tags: r, rcpp, failed-installation, rstan

I've successfully installed rstan, but when I try to attach it with `library(rstan)` I get a pop-up window with the title "RGui (64-bit): Rgui.exe - Entry Point Not Found" and the message content

> The procedure entry point EXTPTR_PTR could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\MyName\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\Rcpp\libs\x64\Rcpp.dll.

In the R console itself I get

```
> library(rstan)
Loading required package: StanHeaders
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstan’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I'm running 4.0.0 (2020-04-24) 'Arbor Day', on a 64 bit Windows machine with Windows 10.

I thought this might have been an issue with Rtools ([Rtools 4.0 not found during package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020444/rtools-4-0-not-found-during-package-installation)), but having reinstalled rtools40 and properly added it to my path - and then reinstalling *all* of my packages to make sure there were no dependency issues - the problem with rstan persists. Any idea what might be going wrong here, and how I can get rstan working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick ones:

1. Did you build it yourself from source, or did you install binaries?
2. You should probably upgrade to R 4.0.2 as there *were* known issues with 4.0.0 and 4.0.1.
3. There is no issue with Rcpp per se; it builds on Windows as it should (see CRAN check pages).

But we did have numerous reports on the issue in 2. So please upgrade R to 4.0.2 and try that.

Answer (score -1):

We need to updata R. In your script does the following:

First install the package

```
install.packages("installr")
```

Then:

```
library(installr)
updateR()
```

After that we install the last R update.

This help me to fix the error of `Can't load the library in Windows - EXTPTR_PTR could not be located in the dynamic library`